# Markov chain graphics in igraph

Tags: r, igraph, markov-chains

I don't understand why the transition state labels are incorrect when I plot my markov chain as an `igraph` object.  The labels are correct when plotted through the `markovchain` package.  Probably something simple I am doing wrong.

Example below.

```
library(markovchain)
library(igraph)


tmD <- matrix(c(0.7,0.2,0.1, 0.4,0.3,0.3, 0.2,0.4,0.4), nrow = 3, byrow = TRUE)

dtmcD <-new("markovchain", transitionMatrix=tmD, 
                           states=c("Cheerful", "So-So","Gloomy"), name="mood")
g <- as(dtmcD, "igraph")

V(g)["Cheerful"]$color<-"red"
V(g)["So-So"]$color<-"green"
V(g)["Gloomy"]$color<-"blue"

plot(g, vertex.color=V(g)$color, vertex.size=20, vertex.label.cex=1.5,
        vertex.label.dist=3, edge.arrow.size=0.2, , edge.label=tmD)

plot(dtmcD, vertex.size=20, vertex.label.color="black", 
             vertex.label.dist=6 , edge.arrow.size=0.2, , main="Mood")
```

Comment: Pass the edge attributes to the label., and curve the edges a bit to see them.. so add `edge.label=E(g)$prob, edge.curved=0.2` to the plot

Comment: Thank you so much for the help...your solution fixed my issue... I was trying to accept your answer but am new to stackoverflow and I don't see the checkbox that is supposed to appear for me to accept...

Comment: Hi mdsailing, you're welcome. The above is a comment, rather than an answer, so you cant accept - but thanks. As it has fixed the issue please consider answering it your self in the answer section - [this is encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)